# TypeORM one to many relation find empty array

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, postgresql, typeorm

can anyone tell me how should I query for empty `@OneToMany` relation using `find` and Postgres? The main issue is that I cannot use QueryBuilder because I created a Pagination System for all of those elements. I have 2 entities `Shipment` and `Parcel`. The shipment has `@OneToMany` relation to `Parcel` and `Parcel` has `@ManyToOne` relation to `Shipment`. When I run the code:

```js
const result = await this.gDatabaseService.manager.getRepository(Shipment).find({
  where: {
    parcels: IsNull(),
  },
   relations: ['parcels'],
});
```

I always get the same results - in SQL theres no information about the relation

`ShipmentEntity`

```js
@Entity('shipments')
@TableInheritance({ column: { type: 'varchar', name: 'type' } })
/**
 * Parcel entity
 */
export default class ShipmentEntity {

  /**
   * ID primary column
   */
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid', { name: 'id' })
  public id: string;

  @Column({ type: 'enum', enum: EShipmentType })
  public type: EShipmentType;

  @ManyToOne(() => AddressEntity)
  public sender: AddressEntity;

  @ManyToOne(() => AddressEntity)
  public receiver: AddressEntity;

  @OneToMany(() => ParcelEntity, (parcel) => parcel.shipment)
  public parcels?: ParcelEntity[];

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  public comment?: string;

  @CreateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamp' })
  public createdAt: Date;

  @ManyToOne(() => TenantEntity, (tenant) => tenant.id)
  public tenant: TenantEntity;

  @ManyToOne(() => WarehouseEntity, (warehouse) => warehouse.id)
  public warehouse: WarehouseEntity;

}
```

`ParcelEntity`

```js
@Entity('parcels')
@TableInheritance({ column: { type: 'varchar', name: 'type' } })
/**
 * Parcel entity
 */
export default class ParcelEntity {

  /**
   * ID primary column
   */
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid', { name: 'id' })
  public id: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => ShipmentEntity, (shipment) => shipment.parcels)
  public shipment: ShipmentEntity;

  /**
   * Parcel quantity
   */
  @Column({ nullable: false })
  public quantity: number;

  /**
   * Parcel width
   */
  @Column({ nullable: false })
  public width: number;

  /**
   * Parcel height
   */
  @Column({ nullable: false })
  public height: number;

  /**
   * Parcel length
   */
  @Column({ nullable: false })
  public length: number;

  /**
   * Parcel weight
   */
  @Column({ type: 'float', nullable: false })
  public weight: number;

  @CreateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamp' })
  public createdAt: Date;

}
```

Comment: What does always get the same results mean?What result do  you want to get?Can you list some example data?

Comment: Related: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/6647